# how to pass full model from view to controller mvc4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    i need to export data from a model class to excel.i have tried many  ways but i couldn't pass the data from my view to controller.i have successfully rendered a partial view which displays data in a tabular format.i have used foreach to iterate through model.
 i have one partial`enter code here` view which displays data from model.                
               @model HRMS.Models.EligibilityCriteriaModel
            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Successfully Initiated Employees";
            }
            <div>
                <h2 class="title-bgcolor">
                    Successfully Initiated Employees</h2>
                <br />
                <div id="AllEmployeeDiv">
                    <div class="stackhold-right">
                        <input class="button" type="button" id="printSuccessEmp" value="Print" onclick="printDiv('printThisArea')" />
                        <input class="button" type="button" id="exportSuccessExcel" value="Export to Excel" />
                        <input class="button" type="button" id="okSuccessEmp" value="OK" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div id="printThisArea">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="tbl_allSuccessEmployees" class="TablesBlueHeaders">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bluebgtable1">
                                    <td width="10%">
                                        Employee Code
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="bluebgtable1" width="15%">
                                        Employee Name
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="bluebgtable1" width="15%">
                                        Delivery Team
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="bluebgtable1" width="15%">
                                        Designation
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="bluebgtable1" width="15%">
                                        Confirmation Date
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <div>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.allSuccessEmployeeList)//this is the model which i need to export to excel i have values in model.
                                {
                                    <tr id="@item.EmployeeID" class="highlightRed">
                                        <td align="center">
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeCode, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeliveryTeam, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Designation, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ConfirmationDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


     <script type="text/javascript">
                    function printDiv(printThisArea) {
                        $("#allEmpSuccessDialog").dialog("close");
                        var printContents = document.getElementById(printThisArea).innerHTML;
                        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
                        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
                        window.print();
                        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EligibilityCriteria", "ConfigurationAppraisal")';
                    }
//this is the ajax call on which on click of the button data will pass to conroller and controller method will generate excel report.                
                    $('#exportSuccessExcel').on('click', function () {
                        var postUrl = '@Url.Action("ExportData", "ConfigurationAppraisal")';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: postUrl,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { completeData: '@Model.allSuccessEmployeeList' },
                            success: function (results) {
                            },
                            error: function (results) {
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>


            now i want to pass complete model (Model.allSuccessEmployeeList) to controller which will generate the exported excel.
        Controller code is:
        public ActionResult ExportData(List<AllEligibileEmployee> completeData)
                {//code to generate excel report
                    GridView gv = new GridView();
                    gv.DataSource = completeData;
                    gv.DataBind();
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Download.xls");
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                    gv.RenderControl(htw);
                    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                    return RedirectToAction("StudentDetails");
                }
    My controller doesnt get completeData it shows count as 0.i want to know how can i send complete model to the controller which will export the data to excel.
    i have tried json.stringify but it didnt work.kindly help if any one of the experts have done this issue.
```

and by the way i am always getting error please add some context to explain the code sections or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code.

Comment: Format your question and make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

You can pass whole model using `$('form').serialize()`

Put ur whole markup in form using

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourForm" }))
{
```

// html markup goes here 
}

Then u can use id of the form or form itself to get full model

u can either use

```
$('form').serialize()
```

or

```
$('#yourForm').serialize()
```

Code for ajax call would be.

```
$.ajax({
                            url: postUrl,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { completeData: $('form').serialize()  },
                            success: function (results) {
                            },
                            error: function (results) {
                            }
                        });
```

Then in controller action you can accept whole model as parameter

```
public ActionResult ExportData(EligibilityCriteriaModel completeData)
```

Comment: i have put my whole markup in form.now the problem is how can i iterate through the form to bind to the gridview.i have code in controller as: public ActionResult ExportData(List<AllEligibileEmployee> completeData)
        {GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = completeData;
            gv.DataBind();//Error over here saying A data item was not found in the container. The container must either implement IDataItemContainer, or have a property named DataItem. what i am doing wrong??

Comment: As I said why ur not expecting model as argument and not List, and then aceess list from model

Comment: i have modified the code  public ActionResult ExportData(HRMS.Models.EligibilityCriteriaModel completeData)
        {...} and ajax as data: { completeData: $('#yourForm').serialize() },
            success: function (results) {
                alert($('#yourForm').serialize());
            }, when debugger hits alert it shows blank and on action method we get null.

Comment: Have u debugged in browser if model contains value for List

Comment: Directly you can not assign array to gridview datasource when gridview AutoGenerateColumns is False one way to do this convert your array to arraylist or datatable, then assign to gridview datasource. check link http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/binding-arrays-to-gridview-in-asp.net.aspx